# Handling large data from mssql database using async tasks

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement a search from mssql database from my android table and display the results in listview.
I am using asynchronous task to implement this.

My approach is like this
Use asynchronous tasks to fetch all the data from db and store in object and pass that object to adapter , and it display the results .

However if the data is about 10,000 results or more than that will it be a problem  or not ?
At this case how to optimize the data loading .

It is possible to load data and bind data to adapter synchronously, if it is will it be a good approach ?

Answer (score 5):

You should implementing Lazy loading for a situation like this. The idea is to get and display around a 100 records initially. Then, as the user scrolls down the list, get another 100 records and add it to the list and so on. You can use this library to achieve this easily:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless

Comment: Thanks, i will try to use this , well does my approach not suitable if data is large , also what is the best approach used to load more data from web in mobile

Comment: Lazy loading is the best approach for loading large data into list views in mobile devices. You should be fine if you just use this. Depending on your specific app requirements, you might be able optimize even more later.